# How to write an editor that shows the content of a folder in eclipse?

Tags: java, editor, eclipse-pde

#### Motivation

I have written an eclipse plugin that shows me a list of all files and folders with unreviewed content. When selecting a folder, I want an editor to open showing all files and subfolders that this folder contains. It has to work for versioned items, too. So I have to create the content of the editor within my plugin (no backing `IResource`).

#### What I currently have

Right now I'm opening a `RemoteFileEditorInput` for a versioned file (subclipse) or I'm using `IWorkbenchPage.openEditor()` for a `FileEditorInput`.

#### Question

What's an easy way to visualize dynamic content (directory listing) inside of an text editor?

**EDIT 2010-04-13:**

#### More Context

I want to be able to create some code review comments on a directory listing. For this I want to be able to open a diff viewer to see which elements were removed or added between two revisions of the directory.

I'd like to enter a comment for a directory the same way I do for a text file. That's why I try to display the directory content as a text file - I've already implemented the mechanisms for commenting a text file.

I call the content of the directory editor "dynamic", because it's not really backed by an existing directory in the filesystem. For older versions of a directory I will create the editor content within my program code.

Comment: Try to compare folders in Eclipse to each other or VCS history, you will get an editor with a directory structure at the top, and two text areas at the bottom. I think you could reuse this concept, but with a single text area at the bottom. This way you could integrate all three kinds of resources (local file, remote file and directory) into a single editor.
I agree with Woody Zenfell III below, that listing the directory contents in a text editor is not the most elegant way to solve this problem, unless you have specific requirements to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I don't totally understand your question (and I lack the rep to comment on it).

Is this right?:  You want to be able to open one of three editors in support of your goal:

- An editor for unversioned files (you say you have this)
- An editor for versioned files (you say you have this)
- An editor for directories (this is what you need?)

  - What does the user do here?  What does it look like?

I'm confused by "What's an easy way to visualize dynamic content (directory listing) inside of an **text** editor?"

Knowing that I probably completely miss your point, I would note that your editor can contain whatever controls you want it to (cf. some of the "forms" editors in PDE, like for editing a plug-in manifest) - you'd probably extend `EditorPart`, maybe create a `ManagedForm` in your `createPartControl()`, create a `ListViewer`, `TableViewer`, or `TreeViewer` in there, give it an appropriate content provider, and give it an appropriate label provider.

I'm also confused by "What's an easy way to visualize **dynamic** content (directory listing) inside of an text editor?"

I can only assume that you want to somehow poll or listen to some events and tell your viewer to `update()` or `refresh()`.

Finally I would question whether the directory listing really belongs in an *editor* . . . most navigation happens in views.  Will the user actually be performing edits to the directory somehow, and possibly "saving" them at some later time?

I hope this helps us all narrow down into whatever will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added a section to my question to answer your questions.